# millions of session files generated in /tmp dir then no space left on hard disk and made the website crash

Tags: php, wordpress, session, nginx, apache2

There is a Wordpress site running on the linux server.

These days seems it was hacked.

Millions of session files generated in /tmp dir.

Then my server crashed.

It occured several times,both in apache2 and nginx.

At first I guess WP super cache caused these problems , but it just happened again after I closed that plugins.

Is there any way to fix this problems?

Was my site attacked or here is something wrong in setting?

I'm just a newbie. Thank you so much !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a nice question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thank you for your advice , I'll move my question to serverfault.

Comment: try to restrict number of login attempts